# US/Can - Maximum current in a single circuit in a 100A panel

Tags: battery-charging, circuit-protection

I hope this is the right sub...

I have a 100A pony-panel in the garage. I'd like to have someone add a wall plug for EV charging, ideally a 14-50, but I'd settle for a 14-30 if need be.

I seem to recall there is a rule that any circuit can only be x% of the total supply. I further recall this being 25%? So in this case, I'd be limited to 25A?

Is this correct, or am I having a senior moment?

Comment: I don't see why the sum total could NOT be any value as long as there is upstream protection.

Comment: You'll need to look at the electrical code in your state or province; regulatory things like this are going to depend on location.

Comment: I'll get out my codebook and check after I've had a shower, but IIRC you're thinking of a rule used to determine initial panel size, but also IIRC you could fill that panel up with 100A breakers, so long as the conductors they fed have an ampacity of at least 100A.  The breaker protects what's downstream.